# Why should I unit test?

Tags: unit-testing

I have a problem understanding the nature of unit tests - why should I write them in general. Lets consider following bit of code:

```
public enum ObjectType
{
       TypeA = 0,
       TypeB = 1
}

public ObjectType Type;


public bool IsTypeB(ObjectType Type)
{
    bool result = false;
    If(Type = ObjectType.TypeB) 
    {
    result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now my question, should I unit test IsTypeB? If yes, then why? The outcome of that method is obvious so why test it? I know my question may look dumb, but to me it looks like creating unit tests is doubling the work with no tangible effects. I have a trouble of understanding what are the real effects of unit tests, when to use them and on what kind of methods/functions.

Thanks for the answers in advance, and sorry for ignorance

Comment: In that case of such a trivial function, I agree that a test wouldn't add too much, but for more complicated algoritms it can be a life-saver! On the other hand, as the function is trivial, the tests will also be trivial to write. It's a matter of using some criteria, for when a method or class is worth testing, a simple assignment is certainly working, but for a more intrincate calculation the cost of testing pays off quickly

Comment: If you have a large codebase and you're making a change, how can you be sure you won't break something ? Unit tests allow you to quickly test the system automatically.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

Answer (score 1):

Normally, one of the major goals of testing is to find bugs. There are, however, other ways to find bugs as well, like, static code analysis. Due to time and cost limits, in practice you have to find a balance between the different approaches.  Testing trivial code means that there may be less time for testing the more complicated functions. Therefore it can be a valid decision to focus testing on the more complicated parts of the software.

Often, even if not targeted explicitly by dedicated tests, the trivial functions (like getters and setters) are tested nevertheless: They are often necessary parts of the test code for testing the more complicated stuff (for example for the setup part or the evaluation part of the test).

Looking at your example: It appears to be pseudocode that you have never compiled (`If` starts with a capital letter), you have not specified the programming language, and thus it is questionable whether it makes sense to analyse it, but nevertheless:

The function you have created looks trivial at first glance. Nevertheless, the function is probably buggy. Most likely the condition for the `if` should rather be Type == ObjectType.TypeB.

Knowing this, it's up to you to judge whether it is worth adding tests for the function: Would the bug have caused a compile error (in some languages the code would compile and have a defined meaning)? A compiler warning that you truly look at? Some static code analysis warning someone truly looks at? All this can contribute to an informed decision.